# How can I split a String of dots?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a String which looks like this `"-..."` I would like to split it into 4 simple Strings `"-"` `"."` `"."` `"."` How can I achieve this?

`String.split(".")` and `String.toCharArray()` did not work.

Comment: Escape the `.` as it is a regex symbol

Comment: That will not work as it will not put the  dots in the rsulting array.

Comment: Might your string actually include other things, e.g. `"-.AB.C.D"` or do you really just want each character in the string as a separate string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split using the empty string as seperator:

```
"-...".split("")
```

#### Edit:

Unfortunately this adds a empty string as the first element in java 7. (In java 8 it works fine).

[Faraj Farook's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29469132/2991525) works in java 7 and java 8.

Comment: This will include an empty string at the beginning.

Comment: It's not clear whether this is *actually* what the OP wants. We need more information about the splitting.

Comment: Yes it works well for 2 dots..Splitting "-.." works. But as soon as I have 3 consecutive dots it splits "-..." to  "" "-" "..."

Comment: @HansEn : Huh? What version of java are you using? I tried with java 8 and it splits `"-..."` to `["-", ".", ".", "."]`.

Comment: I am reading the Strng from an Excel file. Usingthe Strnig from the excel does not result in the correct split. Simply splitting the String as above works. I gues i must check what is going wrong retrievin the String fro the excel.

Comment: @HansEn : I tested it with java 7 and it adds a empty string at the beginning (but it doesn't keep the 3 dots together. Most likely that's the Ellipsis char U+2026). Try out Faraj Farook's pattern which works for me it in java 7 and 8.

Answer (score 3):

You can use some nice Java 8 functionality:

```
String[] foo = "-....".chars().mapToObj(String::new).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 "-...".split("(?!^)");
```

This will simply give the array of string for all the characters.
For example the above will give the array of:

```
String[] (length=4) ["-", ".", ".", "."]
```

Comment: or `"-...".split("(?!$)");` or `"-...".split("(?<!^)");`

Answer (score 0):

you can convert charArray to string :

```
String string="-...";

    char[] chars = string.toCharArray(); 
     List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(); 

     for (char stringChar : chars) { 
          stringList.add(String.valueOf(stringChar)); 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `"-...".ToCharArray()` as it's working perfectly on my computer.
You might need to use  `"-...".ToCharArray()` instead of  `"-...".toCharArray()`.